# Threads with Robot freeze in JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with a JavaFX Robot in my application. Since i read that `Platform.runLater()` should not be used for a background calculations, so I've tried to use Task, but unfortunately - unsuccessfully.

To demonstrate my problem i created a simple app with just one button. After the button is clicked, it should count all the pixels from a screen that have R equal to 255 and then, print their number on the screen. But what happens is on the line where the Robot instance is supposed to take a screenshot, it freezes, and never goes forward. If i put the calculation code into a `Platform.runLater()`, everything works. I don't know why it happens. Can anyone help me?

Here are pieces of my code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.robot.Robot;


public class Controller {
    private Robot robot = new Robot();
    private PixelCounterService service = new PixelCounterService(robot);

    public void initialize(){
        service.setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> {
            System.out.println(workerStateEvent.getSource().getValue().toString());
        });
        service.start();
    }
}
```

```
package sample;

import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.robot.Robot;
import javafx.stage.Screen;

public class PixelCounterService extends Service<Integer> {
    private Robot robot;

    public PixelCounterService(Robot robot){
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
        return new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
                //any code put here is executed
                WritableImage screenshot = robot.getScreenCapture(null, screen.getBounds());
                //lines below this one are never executed
                PixelReader pixelReader  = screenshot.getPixelReader();
                int redPixels = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < screenshot.getWidth(); i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < screenshot.getHeight(); j++){
                        if(pixelReader.getColor(i, j).getRed() == 1){
                            redPixels++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return redPixels;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Since I'm using Java and JavaFX 16 for this project, to start it (in4 IntelliJ) I have to add a following line to a VM options 
`--module-path "PATH_TO_JAVAFX16\javafx-sdk-16\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.web` 
 and in 
 `Project Structure -> Modules` 
 add JavaFX lib directory.

Comment: Don’t use awt classes like Toolkit.  JavaFX has inbuilt ability to determine screen size you don’t need awt for that.

Comment: Don’t do stuff like update labels off the JavaFX thread.  See the Task javadoc for info on how to do that.

Comment: Do provide a [mcve] for copy and paste replication with no addition.  Needs imports an app class no fxml for this.

Comment: [Robot](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html) javadoc states “Robot objects must be constructed and used on the JavaFX Application Thread.”

Comment: You probably don’t need other threads or a service at all for this.  Try doing it all on the JavaFX app thread and see if performance is ok for your app, if not, explain better why not, what performance you get and what you need and why.

Comment: You might get better performance if you extract the pixels from the pixelreader to a buffer and analyze that in parallel using [fork join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) rather than getting each color of every pixel individually from the reader, but you would need to benchmark that to see I think.

Comment: @jewelsea I updated my code a little, thanks for tips. Why am I trying to do it in a service is because in my main app (this is just an exmaple of my problem) I have many different threads that work on Robots, and execute many actions (it's a bot for a game, it searches in many different areas of a screen for some icons, HP percentage etc. and base on that it e.g. uses a potion). And the drop in performance is noticeable. It would really help me, if it was possible to use Robot in a service, or i can just take a screenshot and then pass to service in constructor.

Comment: _if it was possible to use Robot in a service_ that's not possible, see its javadoc, _i can just take a screenshot and then pass to service in constructor_ that's the way to go (as @James_D spelled out in his answer)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadocs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html):

> Robot objects must be constructed and used on the JavaFX Application
> Thread.

So you need to take your screenshot on the JavaFX Application Thread; you can then process it on the background thread:

```
public class PixelCounterService extends Service<Integer> {
    private Robot robot;

    public PixelCounterService(Robot robot){
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        WritableImage screenshot = robot.getScreenCapture(null, screen.getBounds());
        PixelReader pixelReader  = screenshot.getPixelReader();
        return new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                int redPixels = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < screenshot.getWidth(); i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < screenshot.getHeight(); j++){
                        if(pixelReader.getColor(i, j).getRed() == 1){
                            redPixels++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return redPixels;
            }
        };
    }
}
```